# Insert a copy of existing row using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using entity framework. I have a table with auto generated primary key and lot of foriegn key relationship with other master data tables. We need a copy functionality, wherein we can select any existing row from the table and insert that as a copy in the same table.

I need to copy all the fields, but it should be a different record, and need the procedure/LINQ  for same.

Please suggest, how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
context.Entry(oCustomer).State = EntityState.Added;
```

this will cause EF to think this entity is a new one and after you call `SaveChanges` it will be *inserted* in the database and not *updated*.

If you have an object graph - you need to traverse it and make sure all child entities are set to `EntityState.Unchanged` or they will be duplicated after `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I changed the EntityState to Added and then Added object to the entity set. I am accepting your answer as it did the trick. Thanks!
I just hope changing enetity state should not create any problem..